# Historical Intraday ticks using BLPInterface

Tags: bloomberg

I use the https://github.com/691175002/BLPInterface wrapper for the Bloomberg API.   Normally I just pull historical-end-of-day stuff.    But I need to instead pull some small amount of historical intraday tick data.

In Excel API, I'd do something like:
`=BDH($A$1,$A$2,"2021-09-17 14:29:00","2021-09-17 14:30:00","Dir=V","IntrRw=true","Headers=Y","Dts=S","cols=4;rows=1195", "Sort=D")`

The critical bit here is the `"IntrRw=true"` parameter, which says "Intraday raw forces the historical intraday ticks output. The default option is true"

However, I cannot find a way to pass this parametr into the he `historicalRequest()` function in BLPinterface.

```
print(blp.BLPInterface().historicalRequest(['spx Index'],['bid', 'ask'], 
                                           dt.datetime(2021, 9, 17, 16,29,0), dt.datetime(2021, 9, 17, 16,31,0),
                                          IntrRw=True
    ))
```

If I pass those time-specific dates, it still just gives me bid and ask End-of-Day, not during the 16:29-16:31 time.

But if I try to pass it a `IntrRw=True` parameter it doesn't pass along the extra keyword, failing with `NotFoundException: Sub-element 'IntrRw' does not exist. (0x0006000d)`

Any ideas how to achieve this?  Sadly the BLPInterface seems unmaintained/unrespondive.  I merged a pull-request with it a couple years ago but haven't heard any signs of life since.

Comment: In the Bloomberg API, you would need to use an IntradayTickRequest which doesn't seem to be implemented in the library you're using (see the README). So I suggest you find another python library which can handle tick data.

Comment: I've been using `xbbg` for a while now. That handles intra-day ticks, and there are some examples on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could use the `xbbg` package to retrieve the tick data:

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime


df = blp.bdtick('SPX Index',datetime(2021,9,17),types=['BID','ASK'],time_range=('14:29','14:31'),ref='EquityUS')
print(df)
```

Which yields:

```
                          SPX Index                     
                                typ    value volume exch
2021-09-17 14:29:00-04:00       BID  4430.77      0    m
2021-09-17 14:29:00-04:00       ASK  4432.30      0    m
2021-09-17 14:29:01-04:00       BID  4430.86      0    m
2021-09-17 14:29:01-04:00       ASK  4432.39      0    m
2021-09-17 14:29:02-04:00       BID  4430.83      0    m
...                             ...      ...    ...  ...
2021-09-17 14:30:58-04:00       ASK  4430.26      0    m
2021-09-17 14:30:59-04:00       BID  4428.96      0    m
2021-09-17 14:30:59-04:00       ASK  4430.26      0    m
2021-09-17 14:31:00-04:00       BID  4428.86      0    m
2021-09-17 14:31:00-04:00       ASK  4430.13      0    m

[242 rows x 4 columns]
```

The time interval you supply is based on the `ref='EquityUS'` parameter. `xbbg` has a lookup of what it terms 'exchanges', and uses this to impute the timezone. The underlying BLP API only deals in UTC times (ie relative to GMT), so the package performs the conversion. Hence in the example this is 14:29 to 14:31 New York time (ie UTC-4 currently).