# How can I access TRACE trade data for corporate bonds through XBBG in python?

Tags: python, api, bloomberg

The following BDH formula from the Bloomberg API add-in for Excel works great, fetching all intraday trades from TRACE for a given corporate bond:

```
= BDH( "49407PAB6 @TRAC CORP", "TRADE", "2/1/22", "6/15/22", "IntrRW=True" )
```

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/28/2022 10:34 AM | TRADE | 101.00 | 750 |
| 2/28/2022 10:35 AM | TRADE | 100.90 | 750 |
| 2/28/2022 5:21 AM | TRADE | 101.00 | 0 |
| 3/1/2022 2:12 PM | TRADE | 101.08 | 1000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

However, I do not seem to have much success in implementing an equivalent XBBG function in Python, which is always returning an empty dataframe.

```
from xbbg import blp

= blp.bdh( tickers = '49407PAB6 @TRAC CORP', flds = ['trade'], start_date = '2022-02-01', end_date = '2022-06-15', IntrRw = True )
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: What is `=BDH` in the Excel example? It doesn't exist in my version. And what libraries are you using in your Python example? Why are you importing `blp` but then using `bld.bdp`? What is the leading `=` supposed to do? That's not valid Python, and you've got a mismatched quote. Please read [ask], paying particular attention to the part about creating a [mre].

Comment: BDH is part of the Bloomberg API add-in for Excel; thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250663/historical-intraday-ticks-using-blpinterface  In Excel the BDH function handles both end-of-day data and intraday ticks. With `xbbg` the intraday part is split out into a separate `bdtick` function. AFAIK though bdtick() only allows you to query one day at a time.

Comment: The suggested workaround works nicely, thank you. I am hoping for a more integrated approach so I will not need to query each date separately.

Comment: Well, you can always drop down to the lower level `blpapi` and implement the equivalent of BDH yourself. The issue around tick data is that Bloomberg uses UTC times. So you need to do any timezone conversion yourself: basically this is what `bdtick()` does for you.